# resolving `address` records in dnsmasq does not work

Tags: dnsmasq

We set up a `dnsmasq` to act as a central dns and dhcp service.

We configured the following

`/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
conf-dir=/etc/dnsmasq.d/,*.conf
port=53
```

`/etc/dnsmasq.d/dnsopt.conf`:

```
# do not read resolv.conf
no-resolv

# don not read hosts
no-hosts

# upstream dns server
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4

# authoritative dns server
auth-server=my.domain.tld,10.2.1.1

# our zones
auth-zone=my.domain.tld,10.2.1.1

# dhcp domains
domain=my.domain.tld

# soa config
auth-soa=202008168030,hostmaster.my.domain.tld,1200,120,604800

# slave nameserver
auth-sec-servers=ns1.domain.tld,ns2.domain.tld
auth-peer=10.1.1.1
auth-peer=10.1.1.2

# fixed host records
host-record=ns.my.domain.tld,10.2.1.1
host-record=my.domain.tld,10.2.1.1
```

If we add an `address` record like this:

```
address=/foo.domain.tld/10.2.1.2
```

This host can't be resolved.

```
# host foo.domain.tld localhost
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

If we change it to:

```
host-record=foo.domain.tld,10.2.1.2
```

it is resolvable:

```
# host foo.domain.tld localhost
Using domain server:
Name: localhost
Address: ::1#53
Aliases:

foo.domain.tld has address 10.2.1.2
```

We don't find any clue to fix this issue. Also there is not known bug report.